# SML - Merge Two Lists

Tags: list, sml

I have a SML problem. I need to write a SML function to merge two lists and returns a list of distinct elements.

For example:

```
- merge [1,2,3,4,5] [4,5,6,7,8];
val it = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] : int list

-merge ["a", "a"] nil;
val it = ["a"] : string list
```

I only can create a function to merge two lists but cannot remove distinct elements.

```
- fun merge list1 list2 = list1@list2;
val merge = fn : 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list
- merge [1,2,3] [3,4,5];
val it = [1,2,3,3,4,5] : int list
```

How to write a function to merge two lists and remove distinct elements?

Thanks

Comment: Are the list the function receives as arguments guaranteed to be sorted?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two functions---a function that deletes elements, and another function that deletes duplicate elements. The delete function would take argument (item,lst), and delete all the elements in lst that are equal to item.

```
delete(item,lst) = ...
```

Next step would be to strip duplicate elements. This function takes your list as an argument. You'll have to use delete function delete items recursively, except for the unique element.

```
if null hd(lst) then []
else hd(lst)::strip_duplicates(delete(hd(lst),tl(lst)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have not told us the entire truth about your problem. It seems that if the lists you wish to merge are sorted, you can compare the first element in each list and put the smallest one in the resulting list. This way the merged list will also be sorted.

The trick here is to realize that while you compare them, if they are equal, you don't actually need to include both in the result, while if they are not equal, you need to include them in the right order.